# Dissolving polygons based on polygon attribute values in Python

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, shapely, fiona

I have a shapefile, with multiple features inside. I am trying to dissolve the nearby/adjacent features based on the shapefile particular attribute value (gridcode), but the difference shouldn't be greater than 3. If the difference between the gridcode is greater than 3, it shouldn't get dissolve.
final output should be a shapefile with the dissolve features with an attribute inside having all the gridvalues which got dissolve.

Image before dissolve
[image: image before dissolve]

image after dissolve
[image: image after dissolve]

```
import ogr
from rtree import index
from shapely.ops import unary_union
from shapely.wkt import loads
from fiona import collection

shapefile = #read shp

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

shp_read = driver.Open(shapefile)
layer = shp_read.GetLayer()
featureCount = layer.GetFeatureCount()

idx = index.Index(interleaved=False)

for feat in layer:
    fid = feat.GetFID()
    geom = feat.GetGeometryRef()
    geom_poly_envelope = geom.GetEnvelope()
    
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = geom_poly_envelope
    idx.insert(fid,(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))
    print(idx)
    
append_feature =[]
for fid2 in range(0,layer.GetFeatureCount()):
    feature2 = layer.GetFeature(fid2)
    poly_collection=[]
    
    geometry2 = feature2.GetGeometryRef()
    poly_collection.append(loads(geometry2.ExportToWkt()))
    
    grid2= feature2.GetFieldAsInteger('gridcode')
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = geometry2.GetEnvelope()
    

    for fid in list(idx.intersection((xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax))):
        feature1 = layer.GetFeature(fid)
        grid1= feature1.GetFieldAsInteger('gridcode')
        geometry1 = feature1.GetGeometryRef()
        if fid2!= fid:
            if geometry2.Intersects(geometry1):
                print ('{} intersects {}'.format(fid2, fid))
                print(grid2,grid1)
                if (grid2-grid1<=5 )or (grid2-grid1>=-5):
                    poly_collection.append(loads(geometry1.ExportToWkt()))
              
    shp_union= unary_union(poly_collection)
    print("featurecount"+ str(fid2))
    append_feature.append(shp_union)
    print("appended")
union2= unary_union(append_feature)
```

Comment: In Python, use [GeoPandas dissolve](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/aggregation_with_dissolve.html) instead of GDAL. It is easier.

Comment: The condition for merging is unclear. If there are polygons with internal values of 0, 1, and 5 touching each other, should they be merged into one?

Comment: If it dissolves a 1 and 2 so the should a 5 then be dissolved with the 1 and 2? The dissolved should be repeated until there's nothing more to dissolve? There is multiple solutions to your problem depending on which square you start with

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, so you may want to iterate on it. You can use GDAL/OGR spatial SQL to do this. On the command line, you can do this easily with `ogr2ogr`, and dump the results to an e.g., GeoJSON file. Basically, what you want is the following code, where you need to

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -dialect "SQLITE" \
 -sql "SELECT f.my_field AS field0, "\
       "ST_UNION(f.geometry) AS geometry " \
       "FROM the_file AS f " \
       "GROUP BY my_field" \
 output.geojson the_file.shp
```

My SQL is very rusty, so the code above does not deal with the grid cell difference constraint. I'm guessing some form of inner join in the SQL might solve this.